# Code not working on server

Tags: php, getid3

this is my code to get image from song but it does not working.

```
<?php 
    include('getID3-master/getid3/getid3.php');

    function get_client_ip() {
        $ipaddress = '';
        if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
           $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        else
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
        return $ipaddress;
    }

    $ip=get_client_ip();
    if(!empty($_FILES)){

            $targetDir =get_template_directory_uri()."/uploads/";
             $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
             $fileName = str_replace(' ','',  $fileName);
            $targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;

            $user_id=get_current_user_id();
            $target = get_template_directory()."/uploads/".$fileName; 
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target)){
                $Path=$target;
                $getID3 = new getID3;
                $OldThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($Path);

            if(isset($OldThisFileInfo['comments']['picture'][0])){
                $Image='data:'.$OldThisFileInfo['comments']['picture'][0]['image_mime'].';charset=utf-8;base64,'.base64_encode($OldThisFileInfo['comments']['picture'][0]['data']);
              }

            if(get_current_user_id())
                {

                $data=array(
                'file_name' => $fileName,
                'uploaded' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'user_ip' => $ip,
                'image' =>$Image
             );
             }else{
                 $data=array(
                'file_name' => $fileName,
                'uploaded' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                'user_id' => 0,
                'user_ip' => $ip,
                 'image' =>$Image               
             );

            }

         $wpdb->insert( 'files', $data);

        } 


    }
    ?>
```

I think there is a problem with the file path.but not sure please help.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: add this at top of the file: `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`